# jax-ws change soap response

Tags: service, web, jax-ws

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify response of web service with JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140583/modify-response-of-web-service-with-jax-ws)

I'm implementing a web service with jax-ws, I want to customise the soap response

```
response now : 
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetAmountResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.dsi.otn.com/dab">
         <etat>0</etat>
         <montant>500.0</montant>
      </ns2:GetAmountResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

to customize to this response :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAmountResponse xmlns="http://ws.dsi.otn.com/dab">
         <etat>0</etat>
         <montant>500.0</montant>
      </GetAmountResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: there is no problem, but I want to change the response like the second

Comment: no, I want to change <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> to <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">, and <ns2:GetAmountResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.dsi.otn.com/dab"> to <GetAmountResponse xmlns="http://ws.dsi.otn.com/dab">, it's clear now no ?